# Random Line of Carets in HTML Page

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I'm making a web app with Django, bootstrap, HTML, CSS, and JS.  I'm generating some API results to a table using template building in Django.  In between an H1 for the table and the table, there is this random line of carets.  When I inspect them, it can't find an element in the DOM.  Here's the code for the h1 and table start:

```
{% if body %}
<a href="#results"></a><h1 style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: 
center;text-align: center;">RESULTS</h1>
{% endif %}
<table id="searchResults" class="table .table-hover" width="100%">
```

And here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

EDIT:  Here's what's in the table:

```
{% if body %}
<a href="#results"></a><h1 style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;text-align: center;">RESULTS</h1>
{% endif %}
<table id="searchResults" class="table table-hover" width="100%">
  {% if body %}
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Song</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {% endif %}
  {% for result in body %}
  {% if result.position <= 9 %}
  <tr name="1">
  {% endif %}
  {% if result.position > 9 %} 
  <tr style="display:none" name="2">
  {% endif %}
  {% if result.position > 19 %} 
  <tr style="display:none" name="3">
  {% endif %}
    <td>{{ result.title }}</td>>
    <td>
    {% for artist in result.artists %}
    {{ artist }}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
    <td><a href='{{ result.url }}'><img src="{{ result.image }}" height="64" width="64"><br>Go to {{ result.platform }}</a></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: What's inside of the `table` markup? It seems like you have an extra `>` in your Django template, and it's being duplicated because of a loop.

Comment: Can you show your full html code ?

Comment: Is that good or do you meant the WHOLE file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>{{ result.title }}</td>>
```

While closing `<td>` you have added extra **>**. Replace your code with this :

```
<td>{{ result.title }}</td>
```

Comment: Agh, shouldn't have made a forum post for that.   I appreciate it regardless!